# Corrupt rendering in awesomewm/openbox

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, openbox, awesome, compositing

I experience corrupted rendering of certain applications with window managers like awesome and openbox, but not with full compositing systems (Gnome under X11, Wayland, etc.). Resizing or moving the window leads to repaints that fix the issue momentarily, but not permanently.

Hardware: Intel integrated on Lenovo Thinkpad, using i915 driver on Ubuntu 18.04, Kernel 5.3.0-45, X.org server version: 1.20.5. I cannot update to a newer Ubuntu release due to work constraints.

Affected applications include Emacs, Evince (gtk3?), vim.gtk2 (but not vim.gtk3!), LibreOffice (gtk3), Onivim2 (Skia), GIMP, or Inkscape (gtk2).

Not affected are Firefox, Thunderbird, Chrome, Kitty. Video playback is also not an issue.

I have tried the following, with no luck:

- Turning on `"TearFree"` or `"sna"` in the video driver settings
- Using an additional compositor, like compton, with all kinds of settings
- Setting `COGL_ATLAS_DEFAULT_BLIT_MODE=framebuffer`
- Changing window manager settings related to bit depth

I used to have no issues, so the problem is due to a recent update, but I don't know which one. What can I do to diagnose the source of the problem?

[image: Corrupted UI rendering]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `intel` driver was the culprit. Removing it

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04
```

and replacing `"Driver" "intel"` with `"Driver" "modesetting"` in `xorg.conf` solved the problem for me.